# How do I add images to a Likert scale?

Tags: image, likert, jspsych

I am new to both jsPsych and programming in general. I am trying to create a browser-based experiment that displays Likert scales on the user's screen, along with images. Specifically, I would like to measure people's opinions of different colors.

My plan is to represent each color using an image of a colored dot, ex. a red dot to represent the color red. Whenever I present the user with an image, I would like the image to be accompanied by a Likert scale: "I enjoy looking at this color" (Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Neutral, Agree, Strongly Agree). So, the user will view a colored dot on their screen, select their answer on the Likert scale, and then be taken to a new webpage where there is another dot and Likert scale, and so on and so forth.

I know how to construct a Likert scale using the "survey-likert" plugin, but I cannot figure out how to add images to the scale. I have tried this code, but it did not work:

var likert_scale=[
"Strongly Disagree",
"Disagree",
"Neutral",
"Agree",
"Strongly Agree"
];

var color_trials={
type:'survey-likert',
questions:[
{prompt:"I enjoy looking at this color.", labels:likert_scale}
],
timeline:[
{stimulus:'img/red.jpeg'},
{stimulus:'img/green.jpeg'},
{stimulus:'img/yellow.jpeg'},
*and so on and so forth through all the images*
};

*(By the way, the above code is supposed to have indentations but I cannot figure out how to write them into the stackoverflow text box.)*

If anyone knows how to pair images to Likert scales in jsPsych, would you please consider sharing your insights into this problem? Again, I am new to programming and am having a hard time figuring out the answer myself.

Thank you for reading this post!

Comment: Welcome! Just wanted to point out that you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how do you format your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML `<img>` tags to embed the images into either the `prompt` or `preamble` parameter of the survey-likert plugin.

```js
var likert_scale = [ "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree" ];

var trial_option_1 = {
    type: 'survey-likert',
    preamble: '<img src="img/red.jpeg"></img>',
    questions: [
        {prompt: 'I enjoy looking at this color.', labels: likert_scale}
    ]
}

var trial_option_2 = {
    type: 'survey-likert',
    questions: [
        {
            prompt: '<img src="img/red.jpeg"></img><p>I enjoy looking at this color.</p>', 
            labels: likert_scale
        },
        {
            prompt: '<img src="img/green.jpeg"></img><p>I enjoy looking at this color.</p>', 
            labels: likert_scale
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: BTW, there is a dedicated jsPsych support forum at: https://github.com/jspsych/jsPsych/discussions